# How to use beaker with GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, beaker

Hi I'm going to use an own session object and I'm trying to apply beaker with python. Can you tell me how to use it with google app engine? I've got the following code and then I'm unsure how to proceed:

```
    session_opts = {
        'session.cookie_expires': True,
        'session.type': 'ext:google',
        'session.key': 'mykey.beaker.session.id',
    }

    def main():
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        application = webapp.WSGIApplication([(...
... handlers          ],debug=True)
        application = SessionMiddleware(application, session_opts)

        util.run_wsgi_app(application)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://beaker.groovie.org/sessions.html) says:

> Once the SessionMiddleware is in
>   place, a session object will be made
>   available as **beaker.session** in the
>   WSGI environ.

In Google App Engine you can access the beaker session dictonary object from a WebHandler with:

```
session = self.request.environ['beaker.session']
```

the session is a [Python dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) where you can basically put data with:

```
session['somekey'] = 'foo'
```

or get data using:

```
my_var = session['somekey']
```

A simple Counter example would be something like this:

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    session = self.request.environ['beaker.session']

    if 'counter' in session:
       counter = session['counter'] + 1
       session['counter'] = counter
    else:
       session['counter'] = 1

    self.response.out.write('counter: %d' % counter)
```